# How to output a percentage of a dollar input amount?

Tags: java, output, percentage

I'm in the middle of my first assignment, and I'm totally and utterly stuck.

The user inputs the New Purchase Price of their vehicle, eg: $40000, and then the output has to show the dollar amount for Age and Distance Depreciation. These calculations are as follows:

**age_depreciation_rate = (years since manufacture date + 1) * 5%**

**distance_depreciation_rate = (distance_travelled / 10000) * 2%**

I'm okay with that part, but the actual output is in a decimal format, e.g: 0.4, which means 40% of New Purchase Price. What I'm trying to work out is how to output as a percentage of the New Purchase Price, so that 0.4 actually converts to 40% and shows the output. E.g: 40% of $40000 = $16000.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you convert 0.4 to 40% without a computer? Ask the computer to do the same.

Comment: There is no magic.  You have to actually print out that symbol, java will not do it for you.

Comment: `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: `years since manufacture date` is not a Java variable. You might want to learn some basics.

Comment: The System.out.println() command I have used so far is as follows: System.out.println("Age Depreciation Amount: " + (2015 - yearManuf1 + 1) * 0.05); if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

40000 * 0.4 will get you 1600. 0.4 * 100 will get you 40. You don't need any utilities, you just need basic math.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the problem I'm having is how to actually produce the output as a percentage of the input dollar amount.


System.out.println("Age Depreciation Amount: " + (2015 - yearManuf1 + 1) * 0.05 * 100); // The output from this is 40.0, but I need it to show 40% of the input value.


Sorry if this is really basic stuff, but as I said I'm brand new to Java.